# JDBC PreparedStatement Replace Value Like PDO

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm programming in Java and i want replace values not with `?` but with `:name` like PDO of PHP. Exemple:
PHP:

```
$sql = "Insert Into User (name, age) values (:name, :age);";
$insert = $conn->Prepare($sql);
$insert->bindValue(":name", "Pedro");
$insert->bindValue(":age", 21);
$insert->execute();
```

**Edit 01**
Java (Current):

```
PreparedStatement select = conn.prepareStatement("Insert Into User (name, age) values (?, ?);");
select.setString(1, "Pedro");
select.setInt(2, 21);
```

Java (How I Want):

```
PreparedStatement select = conn.prepareStatement("Insert Into User (name, age) values (:name, :age);");
select.setString(":name", "Pedro");
select.setInt(":age", 21);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Make a custom implementation PreparedStatement to do that.

Comment: I edit de question.

Comment: Thanks, is that i looking for.

Comment: This article here offers a quick implementation of such a class: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html